# Bootstrap Overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing my template with bootstrap which has a fullscreen slider that gets specifics featured images, but when I put position: relative and position: absolute in the containers, the one with position absolute don't stay on center anymore.

Here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vqcf1L5d/

```
<div class="container-full header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            header
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that the header overlays the background and that the scrolling doesn't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute` does exactly what it says: it positions itself absolutely to it's parent display context. This means that your `.header` is not going to automatically center, because it's going to see the top, left corner as it's `0, 0` and display down and away from that point. It's also "behind" your `.bg` element, so you're not even seeing it.

You could instead manipulate it's inner `.container`, though (and fix the `z-index`):

```
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.header .container {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fe634e;
    opacity: 0.8;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/vqcf1L5d/4/

Comment: Hi! I can't see your link.